# Need c code in given procedure

Tags: c

This is an example of finding square roots. I have to maintain this procedure to find the square root of any given number.

[image]

I have got a problem that, I have to find the square root of any given number without using the `sqrt()` function in C. And I have to follow this procedure that I have showed in this image. I have solved one. Here's my code:

```
int main(){

    double i,j,n;

    printf("Enter a number\n");

    scanf("%lf",&n);

    j=n;

    for(i=1;i<=n*2;i++)
    {
        j=(j+(n/j))/2;
    }

    printf("\nresult is %.4lf",j );

    return 0;
}
```

Is this code maintaining the procedure that is given in the image? If it is not, please how I should solve it? I am a beginner. If there's anything wrong, please tell me.

Comment: The code is using [Newton-Raphson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) (or 'divide and average') which works really well for square roots but is nothing to do with the diagram.

Comment: have you tried google `square root algorithm c`  ?

Comment: I have searched google .i have found this which is shown in my picture.here the link
`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Decimal_.28base_10.29` @ Claptrap. 
In image which algorithm followed.

Comment: "Is this code maintaining the procedure that is given in the image?"  No, the 2 methods are different.  1st method works nice with integers. Are you certain the input is floating point and not an integer?

Comment: Please anyone tell me the fomula/mathod/algorithm name that is used in image.or give me solution.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Examples this is another link.I need to solve by this procedure/method